# Mozila Firefox add on for viewing bootstrap application as in mobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am Creating an MVC Application using twitter bootstrap 3. Now I need to test the responsive feature in a mobile . I know there is some add on available in Mozilla that allows us to have the same experience as in mobile through desktop, have anyone of you heard of such add on?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [user-agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/?src=ss) addon.

However mobile device emulation is one of the point where the Chrome devtools are more feature rich than Firefox/Firebug.

In Chrome, you go to devtools configuration and in the Overrides tab check 'Show emulation view in console drawer'. Then back in devtools click on the show console icon, and finally go to the emulation tab. It let you choose a device, resolution and emulate touch events with the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl-Shift-M (Responsive mode) is built into Firefox and will let you work with any size of mobile screen resolution and simulate touch events with the mouse.

There are no presets for specific phones (although you can add new size presets if you want) and you won't be able to spot all differences because you'll always be rendering with Gecko. For increased accuracy you'd have to use a tool that at least emulates different rendering engines. [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/) can be good for that but in my experience it is tediously slow.

If you are doing user agent detection then an addon to manipulate that might be useful but presumably if you're going for a responsive design you will be more concerned with media query behaviours than hacky user agent tricks.